# multiply two input boxes and then show result time nine in third box

Tags: calculator

I am trying to find code to make a calculator of sorts. I need it to be three input boxes where you can type data in the first two boxes. First box divided by the second box and the result is then multiplied by 9 (the nine not shown) and the result or answer is shown in the third text box. With some sort of compute or calculate button.

Comment: Please read [How to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 0):

This should do it:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace calculator
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            int answer = (Convert.ToInt32(txt1.Text) / Convert.ToInt32(txt2.Text)) * 9 ;

            txtAnswer.Text = Convert.ToString(answer); 

        }
    }
}
```